# How to inject CSS before show WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview

I need some help on how to inject CSS before showing WebView. Appreciate any help.

I need to inject CSS into WebView from assets, before the WebView shows.

Comment: Maybe show what you tried and not say "I want some help". Flagging for closure as this shows no effort.

Answer (score 2):

You should load url contents manually to your html structure. put this code as page.html in your assets folder.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
    <style type="text/css">
        // your css code here
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    ${body}
</body>
</html>
```

then in your java code:

```
String pageBody; // get page body by httpUrlConnection or okhttp or...

String html = FileUtils.readFromAssets("page.html", context);

// replace pageBody with ${body} in your html file
html = html.replace("${body}", pageBody); 

WebView webView = (WebView) getView().findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```